# QlikView Reports - How to add a new column/field to an existing report

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am completely new to QlikView and I have been given the task to add a new field to a QlikView Report. The Report is fed from an Oracle View, and whilst I have easily added the field to the View, I am completely at sea as to how I get QlikView to then add this new field where the outcome is simply displayed in a table on the UI.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

Find the place in the Qlik script where the data is loaded from the View. Add the new field to the rest of the fields.
It depends how the script is written but few possible examples:

- In this example all fields are loaded from the view. Nothing to be added just reload the script and the field will be available in the UI

```
MyTable:
SQL Select * From MyView;
```

- Specific fields are loaded from the view. Just add the new field and reload

```
MyTable:
SQL Select 
  Field1, 
  Field2,
  Field3
  ...
 From MyView;
```

- specific fields are loaded from the view and then only subset of fields are exposed to the data model/UI. In this case you'll have to add the field in both places - sql part and above it

```
MyTable:
Load
  Field1,
  Field2
  ...
;
SQL Select 
  Field1, 
  Field2,
  Field3
  ...
 From MyView;
```

- The above examples are covering the cases where no additional manipulations are made on the data. Its quite common to load the raw data (from the view) and then use the result table in later stages in the script. This highly depends on your data, data model and requirements. In this case you'll have to trace the usage of the raw table and add the field in the result tables. For example:

```
RawData:
SQL select 
  Field1,
  Field2
from MyView;

//... some other script

FinalTable
Load 
  Field1,
  Field2
Resident
  RawData;

join 

Load * From SomeOtherQlikTable;

Drop Table RawData;
```

As you can see `RawData` is a temporary table that is dropped at the end of the script. In this case adding the field only to `RawData` table will not bring the field to the data model at end. And you'll have to add the field to `FinalTable` as well